# Use Jquery to load() just one of the @media only screen sizes in my css file

Tags: jquery, css

My css files contain 6 @media only screen sizes.
But, while minifying my css it occurred to me that mobile users are still going to get six times the data they need and that I really should only give them the @media appropriate to their screen size.

Rather than carve up all my css files and link to them based on size, is there an existing trick to use jquery or js to reach into a css file and extract only the appropriate @media? I'm hoping someone has something like the jquery load() that uses the # to identify a section of a page to extract or perhaps something like `source media="(min-width: 160px)"  srcset="/14_xSmall.jpg"` that I use to load different size images.

Is this possible? It would save a lot of unnecessary data transfer.
TIA

Comment: there is : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset that should do what you look for.  JavaScript has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Thanks. I use something similar for images already, but I'd like to know how to get just a small section of css from a css file. Did I miss something in my read of that page?

Comment: oops I missed your second link. I'll get back to you.

Comment: matcmedia can be used to update a css var() if that helps you figure out a way matching your need.

Comment: Thanks. I've got my work cut out for me.